# Interpreter optimization in Python

Tags: python, string, optimization

Say I have a string in `x`, is the Python interpreter smart enough to know that: `string.replace(x, x)` should be converted to a `NOP`?

How can I find this out? Are there any references that show what type of optimizations the interpreter is able to do dynamically based on syntactic analysis?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, Python cannot make assumptions about NOPs; it cannot know at compile time what type of object `string` is, nor that it'll remain that type throughout the run of the program.

There *are* some optimisations applied at compile time, mostly in the [peephole optimiser](http://hg.python.org/cpython/file/98a2e215ff01/Python/peephole.c). This does things like:

- Replace `list` and `set` literals used in a membership test with immutable equivalents; this only works if the literal object is not assigned, only used in a comparison; e.g.:

  ```
  if foo in ['spam', 'ham', 'eggs']:
  ```

  is replaced with

  ```
  if foo in ('spam', 'ham', 'eggs'):
  ```
- Replace simple calculations with the result:

  ```
  one_week = 7 * 24 * 60 * 60
  ```

  is replaced with

  ```
  one_week = 604800
  ```

  This happens for sequences too; `'neener' * 3` is replaced with the result of that multiplication, provided the resulting sequence stays under 21 elements.

These optimisations are only possible because it concerns immutable literal values; constant values that are fully under control of the interpreter and can be relied upon to not switch types halfway through execution.

Comment: The compile-time optimizations can be explored a little by disassembling examples with the `dis` module.