# Julia vs Python compiler/interpreter optimization

Tags: optimization, julia

I recently asked the following question about Python:
[Interpreter optimization in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25248595/interpreter-optimization-in-python/25248625#25248625)

> Say I have a string in x, is the Python interpreter smart enough to
>   know that: `string.replace(x, x)` should be converted to a `NOP`?

The answer seems to be No (although the Python interpreter is able to do [some optimizations](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25248625/283296) through the peephole optimiser).

I don't know what the equivalent expression in Julia would be, but is Julia capable of optimizing these types of relatively obvious 
statements?

Comment: I think the answer is "sometimes", in that it will propagate constants and eliminate dead code. Its hard to answer without a more specific case as it can be very difficult to infer for the compiler in some cases (although its probably easier than in Python)

Answer (score 4):

### Relying on the compiler

The question is can Julia provide enough information to LLVM so that the compiler can optimize things?

From your example yes, and you can verify with code_native. For example the answer is premultiplied and unnecessary assignment to x is optimized away and the function always returns a constant

```
julia> f()=(x=7*24*60*60)
f (generic function with 1 method)

julia> code_native(f,())
    .section    __TEXT,__text,regular,pure_instructions
Filename: none
Source line: 1
    push RBP
    mov  RBP, RSP
    mov  EAX, 604800
Source line: 1
    pop RBP
    ret
```

### Optimization from typing

And it can go a bit further at times because more knowledge is available from type information. The converse is that the ***Any*** type and globals are to be avoided if possible.

#### Example

In case I, the comparison needs to be made because y might be greater than 256, but in the 2nd case since it's only 1 byte, it's value can't be greater than 256 and the function will be optimized to always return 1.

#### Case I

```
julia> g(y::Int16)=(y<256?1:0)
g (generic function with 1 method)

julia> code_native(g,(Int16,))
    .section    __TEXT,__text,regular,pure_instructions
Filename: none
Source line: 1
    push RBP
    mov  RBP, RSP
    cmp  DI, 256
Source line: 1 
    setl  AL
    movzx EAX, AL
    pop   RBP
    ret
```

#### Case II

```
julia> g(y::Int8)=(y<256?1:0)
g (generic function with 2 methods)

julia> code_native(g,(Int8,))
    .section    __TEXT,__text,regular,pure_instructions
Filename: none
    Source line: 1
    push RBP
    mov  RBP, RSP
    mov  EAX, 1
Source line: 1
    pop  RBP
    ret
```